regression metric for dataset with wide target values range?
I have a dataset of about 100 images. Each image has a label, which is a numerical value. The models need to learn from the images to predict the numerical labels. However, the problem is that I don't know what the best metric is. For example, R² might not change with parameter adjustments, while other metrics like MSE, MAE, etc., can change significantly. But I'm not sure which metric to choose to fit the model. One thing to note about my dataset is that the six target values (the labels) have a large distance between them and a wide range, covering target values from 50 to 2400.
